# Why this question has been closed?

Tags: discussion

Why this my question has been closed?

https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/109273/is-this-picture-of-the-universe-valid

Comment: What is unclear about the message given?

Comment: @Kyle Kanos well I replied to your message. For excample you claim that I suggest a non-interacting observer, which is untrue. Youyh simply did not readr the question throroughly.

Comment: @Kyle Kanosn If youb thinik I postulated any fact not established by physics, please point at it in the answer.

Comment: AFAICT, postulating facts from established physics and *connecting* them together to make up something fantastic does *not* mean that the statements are combined true.

Comment: Further, if your assessment *were* actually established fact, you would not be asking "Is this a valid interpretation."

Comment: @Kyle Kanos well I agree with your comment that connecting established facts does not make the combined statement necessary true. That's why was my question: is the connection between the facts was wrong, please tell me, where.